# Docker compose requiring files that aren't related to the service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have reproduced my issue in a a simple docker file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  node:
    entrypoint: "/bin/bash -c"
    image: node:14.17.4
    working_dir: /app/
    env_file:
      - .env

  node2:
    entrypoint: "/bin/bash -c"
    image: node
    working_dir: /app/
    env_file:
      - .env
      - .env.another
```

Now, with both `.env` and `.env.another` in the same directory, both of these commands execute fine:

```
➜ docker-compose run node  "node -v"
Creating docker-huh_node_run ... done
v14.17.4
➜ docker-compose run node2  "node -v"
Creating docker-huh_node2_run ... done
v16.10.0
```

However, if I now remove .env.another (update: to clarify, remove from disk, not change the `docker-compose.yaml`) which is not required by `node`, I get the following:

```
➜  docker-compose run node  "node -v" 
ERROR: Couldn't find env file: /Users/USER/path/to/here/.env.another
```

My expectation would be that without this file, this service inside the docker would execute fine? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to do a `docker-compose down --remove-orphans` and then `docker-compose run node "node -v"`

There are probably some configuration that the docker-compose instance is not forgetting. docker-compose is not k8s so it's not smart enough to sync the running instance with the docker-compose file.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work for me :( 

```
➜ docker-compose down --remove-orphans
ERROR: Couldn't find env file: path/to/file/.env.another
➜ touch .env.another
➜ docker-compose down --remove-orphans
Removing docker-huh_node2_run_7335bb0ed929 ... done
Removing docker-huh_node_run_24f743a3744a  ... done
(More but removed)
Removing network docker-huh_default
➜ rm .env.another 
➜ docker-compose run node  "node -v"  
ERROR: Couldn't find env file: path/to/file/.env.another
```

Comment: Okay. You might be facing something one of my friend faces. Which is you’re terminal is on another path and you’re editing another file on another path.

Comment: That doesn't feel related. This is all in the same terminal fwiw. I have also edited the question to reflect that I meant to delete the .env.another file. not edit the docker-compose.

Comment: In that case. The env_file properly of a service is required and is not optional. That’s how docker-compose file spec is defined.

Comment: But I have left the `.env` that is required for the `node` service. `.env.another` is only required by `node2` which is not what I am running. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Still the docker-compose yaml file spec is verified which ever service you target.